# PHP, SQL insert value into tables that are linked together?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables,

Table User:
Columns-> id, name, age, position, department, phone

Table Phone:
Columns id, u_id, u_phonetype (foreign key is user.id with on delete cascade and update cascade).

I want to perform this INSERT INTO sql with the u_phonetype from the Phone table:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `position`, `department`, 
`phone`) values ("'.$name.'", "'.$age.'", "'.$position.'", "'.$department.'", "'.$phone.'") ;
```

How do I insert into the values of `u_phonetype` into this SQL? Would I be performing a `JOIN`?

Comment: Which RDBMs, and clarify your question.

Comment: You cannot JOIN with INSERT statements, you have to add to the user table, get the user id and then insert into the phone table.

Comment: @DWolf you actually can use joins in INSERT statements

Answer (score 1):

using php you would just need to use 2 / 3 queries to get this done.

```
// insert your user
INSERT INTO users (columns) VALUES(vals);

// get the last id
SELECT id FROM users order by id desc limit 1

// this is also work if you just do
SELECT id FROM users where name='name' and age='age' "and whatever values you have";

// then insert into phone with the id retrieved from above
INSERT INTO Phone (columns) VALUES(vals);
```

3 step process but under the same connection it should be ok

Comment: This has a race condition. If you happen to do an INSERT followed by another INSERT followed by the select for the first thread, it'll end up with the ID from the second user and not the first. This can be mitigated through either transactions or by changing the SELECT to have a `WHERE name = 'name'` in it.

Comment: You also run into issues if there are multiple John Smith's in the table.  In my experience with DBA, race is better than grabbing someone else's user_id especially with secure data

Comment: This is ill-informed and unhelpful.

Comment: wouldn't necessarily work if you did it SELECT id FROM users where name='name' and age='age' unless these values make up composite key. I think you're assuming a bit too much here.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO table1 (column1,column2) VALUES ('test', 1); 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO table2 (column3,column4,column5) VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, 2, 3);
```